# asp:listbox within asp : wizard server side don't feel client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

i have 2 listbox(consider A and B) and move right, save buttons

1. using jquery i first move the data from A to B. this is the code i used for Move Right

   ```
   $(function () {

       $('#addCat').click(function () {
           $(".ListBox1 > option:selected").appendTo(".ListBox2");
           sortlist(".ListBox1 > option");
           sortlist(".ListBox2 > option");
           selectAll();
       });


       $('#removeCat').click(function () {
           $(".ListBox2 > option:selected").appendTo(".ListBox1");
           sortlist(".ListBox1 > option");
           sortlist(".ListBox2 > option");
           selectAll();


       });
       $('#addCount').click(function () {
           $(".ListBox3 > option:selected").appendTo(".ListBox4");
           sortlist(".ListBox3 > option");
           sortlist(".ListBox4 > option");
           selectAll();
       });
       $('#removeCount').click(function () {
           $(".ListBox4 > option:selected").appendTo(".ListBox3");
           sortlist(".ListBox3 > option");
           sortlist(".ListBox4 > option");

       });


       $('.submit').click(function () {
           //selectAll();
           return newAccountValidate();


       });



       $('.save').click(function () {
           //selectAll();
           return editAccountValidation();
       });




   });
   ```
2. then  i click on Save buton, from code behind(server side)  im trying to get the items from listbox B, there i dont get any items and items count is also 0.

i get that the listbox b items.count = 0

experts please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the changes made by JQuery won't translate to the server; this means that you need to push the changes back to the server using JQuery $.ajax, or store the value in listbox2 in a hidden field, or something like that.  With the second option (store in a hidden field), essentially what you are doing is tracking changes between what was in list 1 and 2...

That can be the problem of client-server interaction.